# Using current User for Ember Data Queries

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember Simple Auth to authenticate with my backend. I almost got it working. The Problem is now how I get it nicely together with Ember-Data. I have some ressources that have end points like this:

> /api/users/:user_id/activities

The Problem is now that I don't know how to inject the :user_id for this route from the current user.

And there are some other scenarios when I want to show the data of another user and in that cases I would obviously pass a different user ID.

My routes are also not helping, since I am showing the activies on the dashboard, and therefore don't have the user_id in the route. Only in the session, or where SimpleAuth stores the user.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the Ember.SimpleAuth repo that shows how to extend it with an authenticated account/current user: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/4-authenticated-account.html

Comment: You are fetching the current user while authentication. That is something I got working. But the question is what is the best practice to insert the current user into several find queries. e.g. when I want to fetch the activities, they are always in the context of the current user.

Comment: Check the example: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/4-authenticated-account.html#L101 The session provides access to the current user via a computed property and the session itself is accessible in all routes, controllers, views and models. Thus you can do this.get('session.currentUser') to access the current user.